# Safari - Javascript - Hiding/Showing Div causes scrollbar to be reset

Tags: javascript, html, safari, scrollbar

I have a HTML document containing a series of Questions and Answers.

Each Question is contained in a div. Each Answer is contained in a div. Each Answer is given a unique id.

The CSS style for each Answer is set to 'none' in order to initially hide the element.

When a Question is clicked on, the div passes the id of the corresponding Answer to this function:

```
function toggle(id) {
    var state = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
    if (state == 'block') {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

(This toggles the appearance of the Answer div.)

**The problem:** This mechanism works well in Safari if the scrollbar is at the default (top) position. Otherwise, this will cause the scrollbar to reset to the default position, effectively ruining the usefulness of this mechanism on long pages.

**Q.** Is there any way to prevent the scrollbar position from being reset?

Thanks.

Comment: **Off-topic**: `getElementById` is not a free operation. Recommend in your `toggle` function that you only look the element up once, rather than twice.

Comment: Is the question you click on an `<a href="#">` by chance?

Comment: @mu is too short: That was my thought as well.

Comment: @mu_is_too_short, yes, you are right.  It is indeed a <a href="#">.  Oops.  (Thank you all for your help!)  However, if I remove the href, then the question no longer looks or acts like a link (e.g. cursor does not change to a hand on rollover). Could you advise how I could retain this behaviour?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, thanks. I shall make that change.

Comment: We have fixed this (or at least attended to it) by removing the link, and then setting the style of the Question such that it appears to be a link (using cursor:pointer). Thank you both for your help.

Comment: if you don't have an href, then it's really not a link anyways. So, yea, don't use the A tag for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said that you're using

```
<a href='#'>...</a>
```

...for the question. That's the problem, that's a link telling the browser to go to the top of the page. You have a couple of options for correcting it:

1. Hook the `click` event on the link (or its parent, etc.) and cancel the default action. How you do that depends on how you hook the event. It sounds like you're *already* hooking the event, so this is probably the simplest solution. If you're using an `onclick=` style hook, `return false;` out of your handler function. If you're using `addEventListener`, use [`preventDefault`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-Event-preventDefault) on the `event` passed into it. (You will presumably already be aware that most versions of IE don't support `addEventListener`, but rather `attachEvent`; how you prevent the default is also different. This sort of thing is why I use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) to smooth over browser differences.)
2. Use the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol instead of `#`, e.g.:

   ```
   <a href='javascript:;'>...</a>
   ```

   The pseudo-protocol tells the browser to run the script code in the `href` element. In the above, the code is just a `;` (statement terminator), which does nothing. You could, of course, have it trigger your `toggle` function:

   ```
   <a href='javascript:toggle("foo");'>...</a>
   ```
3. Don't use an `a` at all. Whether it's appropriate to use one depends on whether it really is conceptually a *link*, which is totally your call.

Comment: Thanks for this. Because we also have links that do go somewhere, we've gone with (2) and it's working great. Cheers.